# Newly added html elements not linking to css

Tags: html, css

I've just added some new html elements to an existing site which are not being affected by the accompanying css rules . When i inspect element no css shows up for these html elements . I know that the page is linking to the css file correctly because otherwise nothing on the page would be as it should . the site can be viewed at http://evolutionhire.com/ . in the consumables section i have a series of divs containing images and spans which seem to be unaffected

```
    <div class="shop-item">
        <h1>BONGO TIES</h1>
        <span class="shop-price"><span class="prices">7 euro</span> per pack</span>
        <img src="img/bongo.png"/>
    </div>

.shop-item {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 56px 0px 0px;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.shop-price {
    position: absolute;
    top: 41px;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    padding: 50px 10px 10px 10px;
    text-align: left;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    color: white;
    font-size: 14px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```

Comment: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fevolutionhire.com%2Fcss%2Fstyle.css&profile=css3&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=en

Comment: have you tried using some other name like `shop_price` instead of `shop-price`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your http://evolutionhire.com/css/style.css file and it is the missing closing curly bracket of your css block:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .product {
             display: none;                      
   }

   .popup {
             width: 272px;                      
   }
```

so just add "}" in the line 2230 and it should work just fine

Comment: So basically your .shop-item class comes under media screen width 768 and from your css code it seems this block should be closed after the class .popup so the .shop-item class will be available globally.

Comment: thank you kind sir . i only added that media query today so i should really have back tracked to see what i'd done . works perfectly now . i'm new to this site . how do i up vote or mark your answer as correct?

Answer (score -1):

**Your CSS doesn't validate.** Errors would keep the whole file from being processed.

Check your CSS here: https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/#validate_by_input

Comment: nope, errors just keep only the properties that has an error from being processed.

Comment: Nope, errors will stop the processing of the entire file.

Comment: well, an addition } will, you're right. but if i write positiiiiion:absolute it will not

Comment: That's not a syntax error. Since the OP's code doesn't validate, that means there are syntax errors.